# access violation at Marshal.StructureToPtr

Tags: c#, sockets, memory, struct, marshalling

Hi there I have this struct

```
 [StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 public struct Transfer_packet 
        {
            public int  _packet_type; // 0 is action 1 is data
            public int _packet_len; // length of data
            public byte[] _data;//;= new byte[DataLenght];
            public void fill()
            {

            }
            public byte[] deserialize()
            {
                int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(this);
                byte[] arr = new byte[size];
                IntPtr ptr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(this, ptr, true);  // error raised
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr,arr,0,size);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                return arr;
            }
        }
```

I am trying to convert the struct's content to a byte array for sending this over the network and retrieving it on another computer, but in the code (mentioned above) I got an error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory.

This is often an indication that some memory is corrupt. I don't why, everything looks fine to me, but marshal is trying to access a protected memory...

How can I convert a struct instance to a byte array? I have done it in c++ perfectly with a simple `memcpy` but in c# I can't.

Answer (score 1):

The `true` parameter is asking the framework to delete the source memory.  Of course, this memory was not allocated by the marshaller, so it's failing.  Try the following instead:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(this, ptr, false);
```

Comment: it bring up memory leak ;(

Comment: my matter is that i want to send a block of data over network in Transfer packet format and receive it in other application which is written in vc++

Comment: @saeed how are you detecting this "memory leak"?

Comment: your right ... it does not detects memory leak but i am trying to convert struct data to byte array and send it over net

Comment: @saeed okay, how does that not do it?  You'll have to be sure to use whatever marshalling attributes (like `StructLayout`) you need to make the structure compatible with the native structure.  Without some indication of specific problems on the native side, I'll have nothing to go on to try and help much further.

Comment: and get it in application i have written in c++

Comment: @saeed You'll have to provide more details, are you still having a problem? If so what is it?

Comment: thanks if you provide me some sample codes or tutorial for serializing a struct to byte array makes me appreciated the above code goes wrong and does not convert it fine

Comment: exception goes down and the problem is to convert struct in correct way this code does not convert struct as well

Comment: @saeed I suggest you create another question showing the details of the managed structure and the native structure.

Comment: Richie i will search more about this if i could not find suitable solution i will post a new question as well thanks for your attentions